# Unable to launch linux container windows server 2019 vers 1809 physical server

Tags: linux, docker, containers, windows-server-2019

I´m getting this error when launching linux container on physical fujistu server PRIMERGYRX2540:

I´ve already try it with different Docker engine versions, but I´m not able to launch linux container. on a vmware virtualmachine, it works fine for me. But impossible to make it run y a physical server.

```
  Docker run -it --name Debian_test debian
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem a78273fb96a8f2398fa6ba93759caf61dc8cf96dd8348f9693dfa94842fe0693_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"container",Name:"a78273fb96a8f2398fa6ba93759caf61dc8cf96dd8348f9693dfa94842fe0693_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}).
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.



docker info
Client:
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
 cluster: Manage Docker clusters (Docker Inc., v1.2.0)

Server:
 Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 19.03.5
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
Windows:
LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1217)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 40
 Total Memory: 127.4GiB
 Name: LMC01
 ID: ISH3:KCT2:4TP3:URUH:IPYL:Q6ND:PYFV:6GJ6:2JWG:TVKH:CLHC:3P3E
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

systeminfo

```
Host Name:                 LMC01
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          BCBLAdmin
Registered Organization:   BCBL
Product ID:                00429-10020-84783-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     10/23/2019, 4:36:08 PM
System Boot Time:          5/15/2020, 12:41:03 PM
System Manufacturer:       FUJITSU
System Model:              PRIMERGY RX2540 M5
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              2 Processor(s) Installed.
[01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2195 Mhz
[02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2195 Mhz
BIOS Version:              FUJITSU // American Megatrends Inc. V5.0.0.14 R1.13.0 for D3384-B1x                       , 8/29/2019
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              es;Spanish (Traditional Sort)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
Total Physical Memory:     130,498 MB
Available Physical Memory: 123,293 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  149,954 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 140,337 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    9,617 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    bcbl.local
Logon Server:              \\BG-PFC
Hotfix(s):                 9 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                       [01]: KB4552924
                       [02]: KB4470788
                       [03]: KB4494174
                       [04]: KB4521862
                       [05]: KB4523204
                       [06]: KB4537759
                       [07]: KB4539571
                       [08]: KB4549947
                       [09]: KB4551853
Network Card(s):           7 NIC(s) Installed.
                       [01]: Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
                             Connection Name: Onboard LAN Port 1
                             DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                             DHCP Server:     N/A
                             IP address(es)
                       [02]: Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
                             Connection Name: Onboard LAN Port 2
                             DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                             DHCP Server:     N/A
                             IP address(es)
                       [03]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
                             Connection Name: Onboard Flexible LOM Port 1
                             DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                             DHCP Server:     N/A
                             IP address(es)
                       [04]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
                             Connection Name: Onboard Flexible LOM Port 2
                             DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                             DHCP Server:     N/A
                             IP address(es)
                       [05]: Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
                             Connection Name: TRUNK1G
                             DHCP Enabled:    No
                             IP address(es)
                             [01]: 192.168.52.67
                       [06]: Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
                             Connection Name: TRUNK10
                             DHCP Enabled:    No
                             IP address(es)
                             [01]: 192.168.52.65
                       [07]: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
                             Connection Name: vEthernet (nat)
                             DHCP Enabled:    No
                             IP address(es)
                             [01]: 192.168.0.1
                             [02]: fe80::3c29:a933:e871:2eab
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Any help will be apreciated.

thanks

Comment: *The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed* is a pretty strong hint to check the list of dependencies against your installed components.

Comment: The first link from Googling the error is https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3126; have you gone through the solutions that worked for other people, discussed therein?

Comment: (BTW, Stack Overflow is focused on questions about writing code, or tools specific to that purpose; "how do I configure my Windows machine to run Docker containers?" is a lot more marginal; it's not about code, and it's relevant to people who aren't writing code at all, since Docker is also a runtime tool).

Comment: I didn´t found a solution yet, but I will look for it through github.com